# How to find a button defined in aar bindings

Tags: android, xamarin, layout, binding, aar

I'm stuck on using aar bindings in Xamarin.Android and hope getting some help.

I have a binding project which wrapped the Java library developed by Android Studio. In the Java library, there is an activity "testActivity" which starts a layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
```

In layout activity_test, there is a button called "topButton".

In Xamarin.Android, I could start the activity like this,

```
var intent_record = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(testActivity));
Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent_record);
```

But now I need to get the button "topButton" and set its click event in Xamarin. I want to do like this,

```
Android.Widget.Button bt = this.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.topButton);
bt.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>  { // do something };
```

But this will throw exception when running FindViewById,

```
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620): Unhandled Exception:
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620): Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace ---
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620):   at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2130)
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620):   at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620):   at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5881)
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
02-27 15:42:20.811 E/mono    (21620):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:732)
```

Could someone tell me how to achieve this? Thanks a lot

Comment: `FindViewById` would need to execute within the Activity (or ViewGroup) that contains the `activity_test` layout. You either need to subclass your Java-based `testActivity` in C# or not use a Java-based Activity and use a Fragment instead and host that Fragment in a C# Activity...

Comment: Thanks much for reply. Is there a way to get the Activity "testActivity" in Xamarin.Android?

Comment: @SushiHangover Or how to subclass my Java-based testActivity in C# to call FindViewById, could you please give an example in an answer? Thanks

Comment: Create a new `Activity` and change it from inheriting from `Activity` to your `testActivity`.

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes, it works, thank you very much.